# Javascript function scope and parameter

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
function b() {
  console.log(x);
};
function a() {
  var x= 1;
  b();
}
a();
//the output is : x is not defined!
```

Can anybody help explain why it will ouput undefined? I thought it would output 1. Why function b() can't get the variable x?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have dynamic scoping. You only have access to variables from enclosing scopes. Variables of the function that called you are not in scope (with the exception of functions that happen to be defined inside the same function they are called by).

Comment: You can pass x to function b from function a.

Comment: `x` is not a parameter of `b`, nor is it defined outside of `b`, therefore it is undefined.

Comment: Local variables can be accessed only in the function. If you want to use it from another function, pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Oh, I see; thanks guys for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing closures with actual invoking of a function. If you had `function b` inside `function a`, then you can access `x` like so.

```
function a() {
   var x= 1;
   function b() {
      console.log(x); // print out 1
   };
   b();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass x variable as parameter:

```
function b(x) {
  console.log(x);
};
function a() {
 var x= 1;
 b(x);
}
a();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see!

Answer (score 0):

If a `var` is define *inside* a `function`, the `var` can only be use within the function. If a `var` is define *outside* the `function`, then it can be use anywhere. Your `var x =1` is defined *inside* `function a()`, so it can only be use *inside* `function a()`. To solve your code, you can simply move `var x= 1` *outside* `function a()`. Here's the code:

```
function b() {
    console.log(x);
}
var x= 1;
function a() {
    b();
}
```

Or, I could suggest you use this instead. It's much shorter:

```
var x= 1
function b() {
    console.log(x);
}
```